# What is being brought down onto the hull of the SeaDragon?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), The Sky People shot one of the Tulkun with a tracker. Scoresby, the
captain of the SeaDragon, a large-scale marine hunting vessel, is
asking about the location of a mother.

> Engineer: Mother and calf. Strong signal. Range 4,000.
>
> Scoresby: **Bring it down, on the hull**.
>
> Sailor: Comin' down, aye.

What is being brought down onto the hull of the SeaDragon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood. He's not bringing anything down *onto the hull of the SeaDragon*, he's bringing order the navigator to bring the SeaDragon *down onto the surface of the water*.

He's distinguishing making the flying ship go in a downward direction (e.g. lowering their altitude from its present altitude) with actually landing the ship on its hull.

You'll note that immediately after he says it, the navigator confirms the order and pushes the hand-lever thingies to lower the ship ("[Coming down, aye](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/715f279e-de65-496b-8dee-025a462a7c05)"). They then land a few seconds later.

[image]